# How do I make a normal HTTP request with a suds transport?

Tags: python, suds

My suds transport is configured to perform authentication against a service. I would like to reuse the transport to make GET and POST requests against the same server with the same authentication. Is there a way to make a normal HTTP request with the suds transport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy and very similar to using urllib, but you must use `suds.transport.Request()`. Given a suds client `client`:

```
from suds.transport import Request

transport = client.options.transport
request = Request('http://www.example.org/document.html')
document = transport.open(request).read()
```

A better way is probably to use the method `transport.u2open(request)`, which just takes a urllib2 request but with any additional authentication handlers added.