# How to use the Typed unmarshaller in suds?

Tags: python, suds

I have existing code that processes the output from `suds.client.Client(...).service.GetFoo()`. Now that part of the flow has changed and we are no longer using SOAP, instead receiving the same XML through other channels. I would like to re-use the existing code by using the suds Typed unmarshaller, but so far have not been successful.

I came 90% of the way using the Basic unmarshaller:

```
tree = suds.umx.basic.Basic().process(xmlroot)
```

This gives me the nice tree of objects with attributes, so that the pre-existing code can access `tree[some_index].someAttribute`, but the value will of course always be a string, rather than an integer or date or whatever, so the code can still not be re-used as-is.

The original class:

```
class SomeService(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.soap_client = Client(some_wsdl_url)

    def GetStuff(self):
        return self.soap_client.service.GetStuff()
```

The drop-in replacement that almost works:

```
class SomeSourceUntyped(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = some_url

    def GetStuff(self):
        xmlfile = urllib2.urlopen(self.url)
        xmlroot = suds.sax.parser.Parser().parse(xmlfile)
        if xmlroot:
            # because the parser creates a document root above the document root
            tree = suds.umx.basic.Basic().process(xmlroot)[0] 
        else:
           tree = None
        return tree
```

My vain effort to understand suds.umx.typed.Typed():

```
class SomeSourceTyped(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = some_url
        self.schema_file_name =
            os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'schema.xsd'))
        with open(self.schema_file_name) as f:
            self.schema_node = suds.sax.parser.Parser().parse(f)
        self.schema = suds.xsd.schema.Schema(self.schema_node, "", suds.options.Options())
        self.schema_query = suds.xsd.query.ElementQuery(('http://example.com/namespace/','Stuff'))
        self.xmltype = self.schema_query.execute(self.schema)

    def GetStuff(self):
        xmlfile = urllib2.urlopen(self.url)
        xmlroot = suds.sax.parser.Parser().parse(xmlfile)
        if xmlroot:
            unmarshaller = suds.umx.typed.Typed(self.schema)
            # I'm still running into an exception, so obviously something is missing:
            # " Exception: (document, None, ), must be qref "
            # Do I need to call the Parser differently?
            tree = unmarshaller.process(xmlroot, self.xmltype)[0]
        else:
            tree = None
        return tree
```

This is an obscure one.

Bonus caveat: Of course I am in a legacy system that uses suds 0.3.9.

EDIT: further evolution on the code, found how to create `SchemaObject`s.

Comment: I am checking if maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522608/how-do-i-make-a-normal-http-request-with-a-suds-transport can help me avoid playing with the semi-innards of `suds`.

Comment: Nope, that was not it, it was the other way around -- using the HTTP stuff for unrelated fetching rather than jacking into the fetching to feed XML to the SOAP mechanism.

Comment: I gave up and went with the [PyXB](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/) package instead, and then I added an adapter to make the tree behave enough like a SUDS tree.